# How to format unicode strings to utf-8 in Python?

Tags: python, django, json, freebase

I'm reading in a JSON string which is littered with u'string' style strings.  Example:

```
 [
     {
      "!\/award\/award_honor\/honored_for": {
        "award": {
          "id": "\/en\/spiel_des_jahres"
        }, 
        "year": {
          "value": "1996"
        }
      }, 
      "guid": "#9202a8c04000641f80000000003a0ee6", 
      "type": "\/games\/game", 
      "id": "\/en\/el_grande", 
      "name": "El Grande"
    }, 
    {
      "!\/award\/award_honor\/honored_for": {
        "award": {
          "id": "\/en\/spiel_des_jahres"
        }, 
        "year": {
          "value": "1995"
        }
      }, 
      "guid": "#9202a8c04000641f80000000000495ec", 
      "type": "\/games\/game", 
      "id": "\/en\/settlers_of_catan", 
      "name": "Settlers of Catan"
    }
  ]
```

If I assign name = result.name.  Then when I log of pass that value to a Django template, it displays as u'Dominion'

How do I format it to display as Dominion?

**++ UPDATE ++**

I think the problem has to do with printing values from a list or dictionary.  For example:

```
result = freebase.mqlread(query)

games = {}
count = 0
r = result[0]
name = r.name
games["name"] = name,
self.response.out.write(games["name"])
self.response.out.write(name)
```

This displays as:

```
(u'Dominion',)  // saved response to dictionary, and then printed
Dominion        // when calling the value directly from the response
```

I need to iterate through an array of JSON items and the values are being shown with the unicode.  Why?

Comment: I **strongly** doubt that's your actual JSON string...

Comment: The whole string is much longer.  This is what the console prints.  I didn't think for the purposes of this question it was necessary to post the original but I will update.

Comment: I'm more interested in the code where you copy the value and where you display it.

Comment: Just updated with more information including the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma at the end of `games["name"] = name,` makes it a 1-tuple. Remove it.

Comment: I cut n pasted that from a list of key-value pairs, thus the comma. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> # example
>>> s = u"Jägermütze"
>>> s.encode("utf-8")
'J\xc3\xa4germ\xc3\xbctze'
>>> print s.encode("utf-8") # on a utf-8 terminal
Jägermütze
```

Don't know much about Django, but not accepting snicode strings seems unpythonic to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str(your string)` to do this.